# Want to change Oracle Code in Teradata Format

Tags: sql, teradata

Below is the Oracle SQL Query which i am trying to convert to Teradata.

```
with Temp As
    (
    select
    A,
    B,
    C
from table1
    UNION
    select
    D,
    E,
    F
from table2
    )
    select * from temp where A<>'XXX'
    UNION
    select * from temp t1 where A='XXX'
    and NOT EXISTS(select 1 from temp t2 where t1.b=t2.b and t1.c=t2.c and t2.A='YYY')
```

Comment: You haven't asked a specific question here. What problems are you having writing the new query? Are you just asking someone to do the work for you? Because that's not how SO works. Show what efforts you have made and describe exactly where you are running into trouble.

Comment: That is standard SQL with no Oracle specific features in it. It should work just fine in Teradata.